# SQL get first reord in each of a list of records

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group

HELP!  Kind of new to SQL.  I've been working with simple statements for a few years but I need a little advanced help.  I know it can be done and will save me time.

Here is my example to try to find results:

```
select top 1 apples, color from fruits
where apples in ('gala', 'fuji', 'granny')
and (inStock is not null and inStock <> '')
```

In the above query I would get the first color in 'gala' apples and thats it.  What I want is the first color in 'gala', the first in 'fuji', first in 'granny' and so on.

InStock isn't as important - it's just an additional filter in the search results.

What I want is a two column list.  Left Column being apple types and right column being the first color result for each apple type.

Comment: Please mention your dbms with version.

Comment: try GROUP BY  clause

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number()` window ranking function to serialize apples wise colors in a specific order. Then choose first one from each group by selecting first rows.

```
with cte as 
(
    select apples, color ,row_number()over(partition by apples order by apples) rn from fruits
    where apples in ('gala', 'fuji', 'granny')
    and (inStock is not null and inStock <> '')
)
select apples, color from cte where rn=1
```

Comment: You are most welcome @BradH. Best wishes.

Answer (score 0):

I think one issue you might have here is the concept of "first". A color is a categorical variable and tables don't typically attach meaning to a "first" or "last" value with a few exceptions. If you're dead set on returning the first row for each fruit, one easy way to get the result utilizes `union all`.

```
SELECT top 1 apples, color from fruits where apples = 'gala'
UNION ALL 
SELECT top 1 apples, color from fruits where apples = 'fuji'
UNION ALL
SELECT top 1 apples, color from fruits where apples = 'granny'
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!  Only issue with this solution for me is that this was just an example.  In reality the list of "apples" is over 100.  I wouldn't want to write that statement over and over.  The first response worked well.